# Calling webservice with the already generated xml in Java

Tags: java, web-services

I need to call a very complex service (It's a HL7 service) it's taking a lot of constant information.

To call from java I need to write all those information and its very time consuming.

I have sample generated XMLs, they have been filled with the constant information, I just need to change 1 parameter and send it.

More clearly; can I intercept the axis client before sending the request and change the "Request XML"?

Thanks,

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  If you "need to write all of [that] information" then it **is not** "unnecessary information".  Please edit the question and try express yourself more clearly.

Comment: I changed it with "constant information". Thank you for the warning.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about testing, and your service uses SOAP and WSDL, maybe SOAP UI can help you.  If you point it at a particular WSDL, SOAP UI can generate all the XML and attendent boilerplate for you.  All you have to do is fill in the values you need and send the request.  SOAP UI will display the response for you.